# What actually is an Installation ID in analytics?

Tags: parse-platform

In my Mac app, I first call `[Parse setApplicationId:myAppID clientKey:myClientKey];` to set things up.

Then I do `[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:nil];` and then things like `[PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"myCustomEventName"];` all over my app.

Finally, I log into my Parse.com account, go into Explorer -> Make a table, choose Custom Events and click Run Query. Now I get a table of all of my events.

One of the columns is "Installation ID". What exactly is this? Is it tied to the machine's unique identifier, i.e., the serial number of the Mac?

Note that I'm only using analytics (for free) and the above API is the only API I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a parse generated identifier which is unique to a particular device. Each device has its own installation instance in the database, which you can see in the web interface if you create a custom subclass of `Installation` (in the same way you would for a user).

The installation id may or may not be tied to a 'real' device value, but you shouldn't make any assumptions about it.

Comment: Thanks, but "installation ID" is still a bit ambiguous in my mind. For further clarification: I call `[Parse setApplicationId:myAppID clientKey:myClientKey];` on app launch, and then while the app us running I call `[PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"myCustomEventName"];` which records some installation ID into the database as I mentioned. The question really is, when I repeat the same thing on the same Mac, will I always end up with the same installation ID in the database? The reason I ask is because I'd like to reliably correlate different data rows with the same device.

Comment: That's the idea, yes, but if you were to delete the app and re-install it isn't guaranteed to be the same (in practice it probably will be, it is on iOS anyway), and if you re-install the OS it pretty much will inevitably change.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!